# How to hide logged in user from User list in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When fetching a user list in my application it fetches the logged-in user list when filtered list also. I want to fetch only the users other than logged in user in my list.

I'm using mongodb and nodejs as backend.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: I use ```Users.find()```` to fetch all users from db. It will return the logged in user too in list.